# pyperclip copies to clipboard but wont paste

Tags: python, pyperclip

I am trying to make a script that automates creating [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) (flashcard app) cards. I need to be able to go through and paste text into fields of the card.

I am trying to use pyperclip but it is not working. Even taking the code outside of the file it's not working like I expect it to. It will not paste any text into the text boxes. It is clearly copying to cliboard because after I close the script I can paste manually and get the output I am expecting. The function also works in the terminal, just not when I exceute a script

```py
import pyperclip

for x in range(10):
    pyperclip.copy('test')
    pyperclip.paste()
```

Here I would expect to see
`testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest` on the notepad I'm focused on,
but there's no output at all.

When run in the terminal this is the output I get:

```
>>> for x in range(10):
...     pyperclip.paste()
...
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
'copy'
```

I can get the output to work by using pyautogui and simulating pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but I don't understand why the other method does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paste` function returns a string. If you execute it in interactive python, the python shell is so nice to print it for you, but in a script, you need to do it yourself - or assign it to a variable for further use.

```
import pyperclip

for x in range(10):
    pyperclip.copy('test')
    print(pyperclip.paste())
```

Comment: Oh okay, seems counter intuitive if you ask me but I get it.